# Magento 2: How to set from admin to see all the routes of my web content?

Tags: magento2.2, phtml, php-7

I have seen people setting something in the Admin, to see all the files routes of all the content in the store, I just want to know how to do that set.

If someone can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by routes ? you mean the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to turn on template path hints in Magento 2:

Go to your Magento 2 admin panel.

> Go to Stores –> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug and set Enabled Template Path Hints for (Admin or Storefront) to yes.
>
> Then Save Config.